# Weekdays in gantt chart

Tags: calendar, pgfgantt

I want to have weekdays in my gantt chart, using the `pgfgantt` package with the `pgfcalendar` package. However the fields for the weekdays are too small.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5cm, y=1cm]
  \begin{ganttchart}{7}
    \gantttitle{Week 1}{7} \\
    \gantttitlelist[title list options={%
        var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x%
        using "\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\y}"%
        }]{0,...,6}{1} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the value given for `x` in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5cm, y=1cm]
```

Using `x=0.7cm` (or a larger value) fixes the problem.

Comment: As of now the solution does not work anymore. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try inserting `[x unit = 0.8cm]` immediately after `\begin{ganttchart}`.